# Open-source, off-the-shelf options for full-article infinite scroll?

Tags: open-source, javascript

The articles on these sites (and others) are using a type of full-article infinite scroll, with URLs that change as you scroll to each subsequent article.

- [Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/04/08/exclusive-michael-slager-s-attorney-dumped-him-as-soon-as-he-saw-video.html)
- [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/christinentierney/2014/03/14/vw-expects-to-sell-over-10-million-vehicles-this-year/)

Can anyone point me to an open source, off-the-shelf script (preferably a jQuery plugin) that accomplishes this? Or are these all custom solutions?

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Studio for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/scrollbar/defaultfunctionalities) includes a custom scrollbar that can help with this scenario.

Here is a [custom example](http://jsfiddle.net/1LayghLe/5/)

Virtual scrolling in ejScroller is implemented using the scroll event. When the scroll bar handle reaches its end points more data is updated in the target pane.

The entire product suite is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program.